# LLVM configuration error

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc

I want to compile llvm on MIPS,
but when I run the script `configure`
there is a warning, `configuring llvm for an unknown target architecture`

and I think this warning will lead some errors,
why the `configure` can not recognize the architecture?

I'm compile on MIPS

CPU:mips

OS:DEBIAN

COMPILER:gcc (debian4.4.5-8)4.4.5

llvm version:llvm-2.9

when I run the script `./configure`, there is a warning

`checking target architecture...Unknown`

`configuring: WARNING configuring llvm for an unknown target architecture`

Comment: What steps are you following? Is it a cross compile?

Comment: Please provide more information, how are you configuring, compiling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be the LLVM-2.9 not support mipsel64 archetecture

The LLVM-3.4 works well